# How to get name of a landmark image (e.g. image of Eiffel Tower)?

Tags: google-places-api, google-maps-api-2, google-geocoding-api, google-places, google-image-search

I want to provide an image of a place (e.g. image of Eiffel Tower) and want Google to give me back that it contains "Eiffel Tower". I need this only for famous landmarks. What API should I use? I tried to look into Google Places API, but I am not sure if it will do what I am looking for. In the EXIF data of images, I do not have GPS co-ordinates (otherwise I could have done reverse geo-location lookup).

Comment: Try to see if you can do a reverse image search using Google Custom Search Engine.

Comment: Hi Pierre, Thanks for your comment. Actually when I give image of eiffel tower for image search, it says something like "Best guess for this image: eiffel tower". This is what I am interested in. Will I be able to get this information via Custom Search ? I started playing with custom search a bit, but haven't configured it yet to provide the information I am looking for. Even if the accuracy is not good, it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Without GPS coordinates, this problem would require a [computer vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_recognition#Recognition) solution, also known as image or pattern recognition.

There is research being done right now, for example see [A new landmark in computer vision](http://googleblog.blogspot.ca/2009/06/new-landmark-in-computer-vision.html) from the official Google blog:

> ... a Google team is presenting a paper on landmark recognition (think:
>   Statue of Liberty, Eiffel Tower) at the Computer Vision and Pattern
>   Recognition (CVPR) conference in Miami, Florida. In the paper, we
>   present a new technology that enables computers to quickly and
>   efficiently identify images of more than 50,000 landmarks from all
>   over the world with 80% accuracy.

But clearly we're not there yet as an industry.  There is definitly no API and your problem cannot be currently solved programmatically to any reasonable degree.

Comment: Actually when  I give image of eiffel tower for image search, it says something like "Best guess for this image: eiffel tower".  This is what I am interested in. Will I be able to get this information via Custom Search ? I started playing with custom search a bit, but haven't configured it yet to provide the information I am looking for. Even if the accuracy is not good, it is okay.

Comment: I doubt it's intended to be consumed as an API.  As an example, the following query gets SSL encrypted, mangled, and redirected a few times [http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?site=search&image_url=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg/640px-Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg)](http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?site=search&image_url=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg/640px-Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

More or less I encountered me with the same issue in the sense that I want to get back the place name giving the image as a parameter. So far I have two possible solutions:

1) The use of the Google Cloud Vision API for landmark recognition. (Not completely free: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pricing

2) In my case I am also taking into account to have the user coordinates (and possible if the device allows me, the direction). Hence, my approach will be to get places in the nearby getting their images. Make image comparison with respect to my input image (giving as well some priority to the closest place), returning the name of the image which is more similar to my input.

Hope that this sketch of the idea helps. I would be glad to here which approach did you use if you were able to resolve the problem. Greetings.